# Meteor Cordova Phonegap facebook plugin build problems

Tags: cordova, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova-plugins

wonder if anyone here can help me on this. I am trying to use the phonegap facebook plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) in Meteor but it crashes during the android build process with the following error:

```
warning: java/net/URI.class(java/net:URI.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
/Users/name/dev/myApp/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java:483: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setColor(int)
location: class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder
mBuilder.setColor(iconColor);
^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

It seem to be related to https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/51 but the solutions in that thread didn't fix it for me.

Has anyone encounter this error before and have a fix?

Thanks!